# How do I position in mono for android?

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

Hello i am new to Mono for android. I am trying to make a Calculator, in a normal windows forms application. 
I can Drag a button or textbox to any position I want but how does that work in Mono for android, I want the buttons next to each other not only downwards. If I place buttons under eachother that go out of the framework I dont want that either..

I am not English il hope you will understand.
please help.

Answer (score 1):

Android "supports", but has [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html) and doesn't endorse, pixel-perfect layout. Unfortunately the Windows Forms-style of dragging and dropping controls onto a design surface at specific pixel locations requires pixel perfect layout, so you can see the mismatch here.

For a Calculator, what you would instead want to do use a [Table Layout](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Guides/User_Interface/table_layout) or some other "resizable" container, so that your Activity can support the variety of device sizes that Android covers.

Comment: Thank you:) Il give it a try